# Solving Diophantine equations involving $x, y, x^2, y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

My father-in-law, who is 90 years old and emigrated from Russia, likes to
challenge me with logic and math puzzles. He gave me this one:

Find integers $x$ and $y$ that satisfy both $(1)$ and $(2)$

$$x + y^2 = 8 \tag{1} $$
 $$x^2 + y = 18 \tag{2}$$

I found one solution by deriving this equation:

$$ x(x+1) + y(y+1) = 26$$

which means, I need to find two numbers that add up to $26$, where each number is the product of two consecutive numbers. Through trial and error I found a solution. From college days I seem to remember that there is a more elegant way using the theory of Diophantine equations.

Can someone remind me or point to me to an easy to follow explanation of the method for solving problems like these?

Comment: Usually (as is the case with your problem) you need to try to 'factorise' - i.e. manipulate the equations to a form f(x,y)g(x,y)=c where c is some number. Try subtracting the two equations instead.

Comment: Yes, **Diophantine Analysis** is the right approach for this problem.  

However, sometimes it pays off to just look at the problem and think about it for a few seconds, test some small numbers as inputs, and try to get a "feeling" for what the right solution should look like. 

Here, I noted that if the solution is a pair of positive integers, then $x$ will be larger than $y$. The pair $x=4,y=2$ solves this problem.

Comment: I don't think there's a more elegant way than you've suggested. Note that by using pronic (a.k.a. oblong) numbers $x(x+1)$ and $y(y+1)$, you are guaranteeing that your summands are positive, even if $x$ or $y$ is negative. Since $\lvert x\rvert \ge \lvert y \rvert$, you need only consider $(x(x+1),y(y+1))$ from amongst the 14 pairs $(26,0),(25,1),…(13,13)$.

Answer (score 5):

We have $$x^2+x+y^2+y=26\iff(2x+1)^2+(2y+1)^2=106=2\cdot53=2(7^2+2^2)=(7-2)^2+(7+2)^2$$

Observe that $106$ can have only one representation as sum of two squares $(\pm9)^2+(\pm5)^2$

See also the [Sum of Squares Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares

Comment: @George, How about this?

Comment: @TonyK, I yearn for feedback from the horses' mouth, negative or positive

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative way to solve for the original problem.
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}x+y^2&=&8\\x^2+y&=&18\end{array}\right. \tag{1}$$

Instead of adding, subtract the two equations and get
$$x^2-y^2+y-x=10\Rightarrow\\(x-y)(x+y-1)=10$$
For two integers $a$ and $b$ to have product $10$, list all possibilities. $$1\times 10,2\times 5,2\times 5, 10\times 1,-1\times -10,-2\times -5,-2\times -5, -10\times -1, $$

Now for each $a$ and $b$, obtain the system $$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}x-y&=&a\\x+y-1&=&b\end{array}\right. \tag{2}$$

This is a linear equation and has solution $x=\dfrac{a+b+1}{2}$ and $y=\dfrac{b-a+1}{2}$ (if instead of $10$, say, we have $16$; use the constraint that $x$ and $y$ are integers to eliminate certain choices. In particular, we can eliminate cases where $a$ and $b$ have same parity because $a+b+1$ and $a-b+1$ have to be even).

Plug in values of $a$ and $b$ obtained from $(2)$ to get possible values for $x$ and $y$ (that are integers). And recheck the values for $x$ and $y$ so obtain matches with the original system (because we are essentially solving $(2)$ and not $(1)$, and we haven't shown that $(2)$ is necessary and sufficient condition for $(1)$ to hold).

$$\begin{array}{rr|rr}
a&b&x&y\\ \hline
1&10&6&5\\
2&5&4&2\\
5&2&2&4\\
-1&-10&-5&-4\\
-2&-5&-3&-1\\
-5&-2&-1&-3\\
-10&-1&-4&-5
\end{array}$$

See that $(4,2)$ is the only possible answer for $(x,y)$.

Comment: This is nice, but I wouldn't say that this is a _general_ method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without the theory of Diophantine equations.
$$x^2+y=18\implies y=18-x^2.$$
Plugged in the other equation,
$$x+(18-x^2)^2=8$$or
$$x^4-36x^2+x-316=0.$$

With a polynomial solver, you get two positive roots $x=4$ and $x\approx4.458899113761$.

Comment: You don't need a polynomial solver: since you're looking for integer solutions, you can use the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) and reduce to testing the divisors of $316 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 79$.

Comment: If you use $ x =8- y^2$, you get $ y^4 - 16 y^2 + y + 46=0$, which is simpler to test because $46 = 2 \cdot 23$.

Comment: @lhf: of course, this is complete overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'd say breaking out the computer for a problem meant to be solved by hand, and readily done so, is the overkill.

Comment: @zibadawa timmy: read my other answer

Answer (score 0):

For such tiny values, the best approach is by exhaustive search.

Considering $x+y^2=8$, you know it suffices to make two attempts: $y=1$ and $y=2$, with corresponding $x=7$ and $x=4$ !!!

The remaining equation $x^2+y=18$ confirms $(4,2)$.

Comment: The OP didn't say _positive_ integers.

Comment: @TonyK true, but that only expands the search space for $y$ to $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$, which is still easily checked by exhaustive search.

Comment: @DavidZ: mh, TonyK is right, negative values allow unbounded solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
x^2+x+y^2+y&=26 \quad 
\\
\text{subs}\quad y&=x+d \quad \bigg{|} \quad d \in \mathbb{Z} \implies
\\
2x^2+2(d+1)x+d^2+d-26&=0 \implies
\\
x&=\frac{1}{2} \bigg{[} -(d+1) \pm \sqrt{53-d^2} \bigg{]} \implies
\\
\text{only sol'n} \quad d&=\pm2 \quad \to \quad (x,y) \in \bigg\{(2,4),(-5,-3),\color{red}{(4,2)},(-3,-5)\bigg\}
\end{align}$$
Cool problem.  Even 3 years, 2 months after the fact